# MongoDB repairDatabase() to other server

Tags: mongodb

My problem is that I am out of disk space and I cannot run repair command to reduce the space. But I have another VPS with enough space, can I use it to save the data here?

Answer (score 0):

The safest bet would be following:

- Stop the MongoD instance on VPS1 (the one with short on disk space)
- Copy the data / journal files to VPS2 (the one which has enough space)
- Start MongoD instance on VP2 and work there.

Ideally I would suggest keeping a tab on your disk space and proactively take action rather than getting into these situations. There are other options as well but most of them have their own limitations.